# How do I create a dictionary that maps out duplicate values to multiple keys and clean data?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-cleaning

I am new to programming and am trying to code things to make simple tasks easier. So right now I am having trouble with a csv file which lists out database fields and the table that field is associated with. The end state I want to have is a dictionary that successfully maps out every single table in which a field appears in. So for example: {firstname;[cust_table,supplier_table,dealer_table]} that has a lot of unnecessary white space in some items. A problem I do keep running into is that some of the database field are given extra white space some of the other aren't, for example: 'CUSTID' , 'CUSTID         '.  What can I do to get rid of this while still keeping the relationship there between db field and table?

I have tried using the reader object in the csv module and was able to create a clean list of all of the fields that I needed and removed all duplicates. I want to be able to loop through this list and use it as a filter for the new dictionary that I will create; adding values of tables to each unique db field (key). But right now I am not returning anything (empty dictionary)

```
import csv

f=open("Data Mapping Information.csv","r")

reader=csv.reader(f)

field_list=[]
for row in reader:
    field_list.append(row[1])

mylist=list(dict.fromkeys(field_list))

cleanList=[]
for item in mylist:
    clean_item=item.strip()
    cleanList.append(clean_item)

reader2=csv.reader(f)

mapping={}

for row in reader2:
    if row[1] in mylist:
        mapping[row[1]]=row[0]
```

Here is a sample of some of the lines in the csv file:

```
ADS,CUSTID             
ADS,ROLEID         
ADS_PARTY,CUSTID     
CUST_TABLE,CUSTID

CUST_TABLE,FULLNAME

DEALER_TABLE,FULLNAME         

SUPPLIER_TABLE,FULLNAME

SUPPLIER_TABLE,ROLEID
```

Comment: the extra line spaces are not present in the csv file

Comment: Just FYI, `list(dict.fromkeys(x)) == list(set(x))`.

Comment: I don't think `reader2=csv.reader(f)` will work as the file was read already in the first code `reader=csv.reader(f)`

Comment: Do I need to create a dup of the file for reader2 then? I’m sure there is a more efficient way to do it than that though...

Comment: Before you do `reader2`, you would need to do `f.seek(0)`

Comment: I think you need to change `mapping[row[1]]=row[0]` to `mapping[row[1]].append(row[0])`

Comment: The change above should be `mapping.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you need.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

f=open("f0.csv","r")

reader=csv.reader(f)

d = {}

for row in reader:
    row[0] = row[0].strip() # remove leading, trailing whitespace
    row[1] = row[1].strip()

    d.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[0])

f.close()

pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'CUSTID': ['ADS', 'ADS_PARTY', 'CUST_TABLE'],
 'FULLNAME': ['CUST_TABLE', 'DEALER_TABLE', 'SUPPLIER_TABLE'],
 'ROLEID': ['ADS', 'SUPPLIER_TABLE']}
```

EDIT: `d.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[0])` is shorthand for:

```
if row[1] not in d:
    d[row[1]] = []

d[row[1]].append(row[0])
```

Comment: @novice_programmer9623 Glad it was useful!

Comment: Can you explain to me how d.setdefault(row[1], []).append(row[0]) works?

Comment: @novice_programmer9623 [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) if the key hasn't been entered yet, default appends a default value, (here, a list reference, `[]` for that key (and then appends to the new list reference `row[0]`

Comment: @novice_programmer9623 See my EDIT at the bottom of my post